# TFS Build task powershell on target machines fails

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I'm trying to execute a `powershell on target machines` build task (template) in TFS server 2015, but getting the exception below.

```
##[debug]System.AggregateException: Failed to install 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployeref1cab6f-da11-4fcc-aae3-9f1433cd11ec' from service executable path VisualStudioRemoteDeployer.exe . Consult the logs below:
Exception calling "SetRight" with "2" argument(s): "Could not obtain the user information."
CategoryInfo :NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
FullyQualifiedErrorId :Exception
  ---> System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Exception calling "SetRight" with "2" argument(s): "Could not obtain the user information."
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.PowershellExecutor.Invoke(String errorContextMessage, Boolean writeResultToLog, Boolean isCancellable)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.RemoteDeploymentHelper.InstallServiceInternal(String serviceSourcePath, String serviceName, String destinationFileName)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.RemoteDeploymentHelper.InstallService(String serviceSourcePath, String serviceName, String destinationFileName)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.DeploymentClient.<RunAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Exception calling "SetRight" with "2" argument(s): "Could not obtain the user information."<---
##[error]Failed to install 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployeref1cab6f-da11-4fcc-aae3-9f1433cd11ec' from service executable path VisualStudioRemoteDeployer.exe . Consult the logs below:
##[error]Exception calling "SetRight" with "2" argument(s): "Could not obtain the user information."
##[error] CategoryInfo :NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
##[error] FullyQualifiedErrorId :Exception
##[error] For more info please refer to http://aka.ms/powershellontargetmachinesreadme
```

I was able to successfully run `Windows Machine File Copy Task` for the same server and configured both client and target servers as described on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/steps/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy). In this task I'm specifying admin login in format remote-machine-ip\username and everything gets copied. The same configuration does not work with `powershell on target machines` build task.

I have found a post with a very similar exception on [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/84d5b4d6-e112-489e-94dc-5f6943caeda2/failed-to-install-visualstudioremotedeployer-in-release-management-2015-rc-using-vnext-template?forum=tfsbuild), and understand this might be a problem of not including the domain. I tried specifying my login in format domain\username, but the remote powershell task still fails.

Below are the screenshots of the powershell task and related machine group:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the extended information:

[image]

There is no information mentioned to support `<Machine-Group>` in the configuration of the `Machines'` Please try to use machine IP address along with ports directly instead of `<Machine-Group>` .

And also use username and password in the `Admin Login` & `Password` directly, then try it again.